# Access token in vkontakte api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, omniauth, vk

I have rails app with authorization via `devise` and `omniauth-vk`. This is code in `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`

```
Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def vkontakte
binding.pry
@user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
token = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"]["token"]
current_user.token = @vk.token
current_user.vk_id = @vk.user_id
current_user.save

@vk = VkontakteApi::Client.new(current_user.token)

if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "vkontakte") if is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.vkontakte_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url

    if request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.email.blank?
      redirect_to "/users/auth/vkontakte?auth_type=rerequest&scope=email"
    end
  end
end
```

I want to tie current authenticated user with his token but I don't know how. 
When I test with `pry` string `current_user.token = @vk.token` I am having the following exception:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `token' for nil:NilClass
 from (pry):11:in `vkontakte'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think you have define `@vk` in wrong place ?? check this code.

```
Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def vkontakte

@user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
token = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"]["token"]
@vk = VkontakteApi::Client.new(current_user.token)

current_user.token = @vk.token
current_user.vk_id = @vk.user_id
current_user.save

if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "vkontakte") if is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.vkontakte_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url

    if request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.email.blank?
      redirect_to "/users/auth/vkontakte?auth_type=rerequest&scope=email"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm afraid it is a bit more complicated. He has a cyclic reference, since `current_user.token` gets `@vk.token` assigned. And `@vk` gets initialized with `current_user.token`. Can it be that `token` variable is to be used for initialization, this will break the circle?

Comment: @Arv I have the same problem again.

Comment: @TheAncient Looks like you are right but I am new in Rails. It would be nice if yould could help me with this code. Thanks!

Comment: @basania, as I said, my first impression is that you should call `@vk = VkontakteApi::Client.new(token)`. Look in the `initialize` method of `VkontakteApi::Client`, if it sets token internally from the argument and lets get it via `#token`method, it is what you need.

Comment: @TheAncient I tested it. I got this. `[7] pry(#<Users::OmniauthCallbacksController>)> @vk = VkontakteApi::Client.new(token)
=> #<VkontakteApi::Client:0x007fbe39953720 @token=nil>`

Comment: Is `token` not `nil` before call?

Comment: @TheAncient It's nil ;(

Comment: Then check the returned omniauth/vk hash, print it out and check if you retrieve right values with right keys here: `request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"]["token"]`... and if you get anything in `from_omniauth` call at all

Comment: @TheAncient I am getting my token from `request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"]["token"]`. From `User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])` I am getting hash. How can I fix my problem?

Comment: @basania What do you get in `request.env["omniauth.auth"]`? What do you get from the call `User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])`? And, take int account that I cannot debug your code and fix the issue, I (and everyone in SO) can only help to find a way to a solution :) You should first understand how OAuth2 works, then how omniauth works, then how vk deals with that... Sorry if it sounds didactic, but there is just no way around

Comment: @TheAncient thank you for your help. I'll read about these technologies/gems.